# python twitter api getting status

Tags: python, api, twitter, social-networking, status

I am trying to get a recent status of a twitter user. I type in the following:

```
>>> from twitter import *
>>> t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(...))
>>> t.statuses.friends_timeline(id="StephenAtHome")
```

I get the following error at the last line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    t.statuses.friends_timeline(id="StephenAtHome")
  File "twitter\api.py", line 204, in __call__
    return self._handle_response(req, uri, arg_data, _timeout)
  File "twitter\api.py", line 235, in _handle_response
    raise TwitterHTTPError(e, uri, self.format, arg_data)
TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1.1/statuses/friends_timeline/StephenAtHome.json using parameters (oauth_consumer_key=i1xQ3YKmmUI9pKlYDmSPeA&oauth_nonce=12051576929978547960&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1371245218&oauth_token=1517563807-75iFGXWHxMvzzsqrIs5W4tCb4OwFG4eisnDYRst&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=m0LDp%2FdkJLMr3sHPnFQkLKlDTrE%3D)
details: {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

How do I fix this error. I know that the page exists

Comment: @user1681664 He's saying that in the Twitter error, the oauth info is all there.

Comment: @TankorSmash I know and I am saying it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that twitter API was upgraded to 1.1 version and `friends_timeline` was deprecated (see [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/get-statusesfriends_timeline)). Use `home_timeline` instead (`user_timeline` should work but doesn't):

```
t.statuses.home_timeline(user_id="gvanrossum")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: the home_timeline works, but I need to see other's timeline. Is there a way to do that?